# argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" || CPLEX IBM

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex, solver

I installed IBM's CPLEX and made changes to the project properties to call `#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>`, but when running the project the following errors appear.

I'm using Visual Studio 17.3.6.

This snippet is resulting in the error:

> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

```
try{

    // Read_main_arg(argc, argv);
    cout<<"Openning file "<<argv[1]<<endl;
    if(argc > 1){
        mono->Read_data(argv[0]);
    }
    else{
        mono->Read_data("Data_FLEET-ICt_2t");
    }

    mono->Create_model();
```

The idea is that at the end, is to generate and save the result of the optimization in a text named `resultado`.

Comment: It will work much better for you to post all pictures and images to Twitter or Facebook, those web sites are designed for that. On Stackoverflow it works much better to post all relevant information as plain text, so that it can be copy/pasted for research. Additionally, Stackoverflow does not very well for dumping a huge pile of code that has a problem somewhere in it, and expecting someone to figure out the problem. This is not what Stackoverflow is for, it's for ***specific*** questions on programming topics. Please see [ask] question, visit the [help], and learn how to show a [mre].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You declared `Mono::Read_data` as accepting a mutable char array (really a pointer; the array syntax is just sugar), implying the function must be allowed to write to it (even though it's supposed to be a file name used to open a file, which is a read-only use). You then tried to call it with a string literal, which is implicitly `const` in C++.

It's an easy fix: You only need to read from `name`, so explicitly declare that as part of the function prototype by declaring the parameter `const`, changing:

```
void  Mono::Read_data(char name[]){
```

to:

```
void  Mono::Read_data(const char name[]){
```

and making a similar change to make the prototype in the class declaration `void Read_data(const char name[]);`

Comment: Thanks, I am evaluating the code further, I may be having some problem with the copiler. As I have this code ready, I will need to understand how to adptar to run.
This adjustment you suggested, opened some new points that I will need to evaluate.